# Subtract two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in pandas dataframe that represent hour of the day in 24 hour format, i.e., `18:00:00`. Both of them are in object datatype and I want to find the difference in hours of the two columns. For eg. difference between `18:00:00` and `17:00:00` should come out as 1. I tried using `to_timedelta` function but it returns 'no units specified' error even after I specify unit as 'h'.

```
d = {'col1': ['18:00:00', '19:00:00'], 'col2': ['17:00:00', '17:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

df['col1']-df['col2']
```

Can anyone assist in this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: added an example @RafaelC

Comment: Don't know if you are trying to simplify the data, but if you have strings, you need to get it into datetime format. `to_datetime` should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert `to_datetime` first:

```
df.col1 = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
df.col2 = pd.to_datetime(df.col2)

df.col1.sub(df.col2)
```

```
0   01:00:00
1   02:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you just want the result in hours, divide by another `Timedelta`:

```
df.col1.sub(df.col2).div(pd.Timedelta('1h'))
```

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In pandas `0.23.4`, can do `df.col1.sub(df.col2).dt.hour` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
(df.col1-df.col2).dt.seconds/3600
Out[524]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
```